# How is autojump tab completion supposed to work?

Tags: bash

I'm not clear on how tab completion with the `autojump` command is supposed to work. When I type `j perl<TAB>` I get a beep and two underscores appear like so:

`perl__`

When I hit `<TAB>` again and nothing happens. When I hit `<TAB>` a third time, the computer beeps and then outputs:

```
p__1__/Users/me/projects/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup  p__3__/Users/me/projects/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup  
p__2__/Users/me/perl/perl_lib                       p__4__/Users/me/perl/perl_lib
```

It seems weird that I have to hit tab 3 times. I'm not sure if I'm using it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first tab is completing the file name as much as it can,  then the auto complete process is starting over.